# How do I get the native type of HDF5 attribute?

Tags: c#, hdf5

I am using Visual Studio (C#) and HDF5 P/Invoke.

I have made an HDF5 file with groups and datasets with attributes of different datatypes (in this case, let's say it is an integer, saved as H5T.NATIVE_INT32, but I have the same problem for other datatypes). Now I am making a code to read data from the HDF5 file. To read the attribute value, I first need to determine the data type of the attribute value. I have tried the following:

```
attributeId = H5A.open(groupId, attributeName, H5P.DEFAULT);
hid_t attributeSpace = H5A.get_space(attributeId);
H5S.class_t extentType = H5S.get_simple_extent_type(attributeSpace);
hid_t typeId = H5A.get_type(attributeId);
attributeClass = H5T.get_class(typeId);
type = H5T.get_native_type(typeId, H5T.direction_t.DEFAULT);
H5T.close(typeId);
```

However, the resulting variable `type` does not match with the `H5T.NATIVE_INTEGER` type, or any other H5T type I can think of. In fact, even

```
H5T.get_native_type(H5T.NATIVE_INT,H5T.direction_t.DEFAULT) == H5T.NATIVE_INT
```

returns `false`, so it appears as if `H5T.get_native_type()` does not return a type, but perhaps a copy or a pointer of it, which is not identical to the type itself. Is this expected behaviour or a bug? Any ideas on how to correctly figure out the type of an attribute value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HDF5 encapsulates data and you should use HDF5 routines to handle them. The values you obtain are called "type identifiers", they are HDF5 opaque datatypes.

You should use [`H5Tequal`](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5T.html#Datatype-Equal) to assess the equality of the type of two type identifiers

```
H5Tequal(type, H5T.NATIVE_INT)
```

PS: I am writing this with the point of view of the C API to HDF5 and hope it applies to your case too.

Comment: I think it should be H5T_NATIVE_INT instead of H5T.NATIVE_INT

Comment: This is an old reply but I guessed that the user used the C# binding [here](https://github.com/HDFGroup/HDF.PInvoke) that provides dot namespaces for the HDF5 library.

Comment: I retract my statement then. I assumed your answer referred to the C API, since you stated that is what you were using. It may be an old comment, but it still proved useful for me, so thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of solving the problem (i.e. to find out the data type of a HDF5 attribute) is to use the tool [HDFql](http://www.hdfql.com) for C# as follows:

```
using AS.HDFql;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main(string []args)
    {

        int dataType;

        // create an HDF file named "example.h5" and use (i.e. open) it
        HDFql.Execute("CREATE AND USE FILE example.h5");

        // create an attribute named "attrib" of type float
        HDFql.Execute("CREATE ATTRIBUTE attrib AS FLOAT");

        // get data type of attribute "attrib" and populate HDFql default cursor with it
        HDFql.Execute("SHOW DATA TYPE attrib");

        // move HDFql default cursor to first position
        HDFql.CursorFirst();

        // retrieve data type from HDFql default cursor
        dataType = HDFql.CursorGetInt();

        // print message according to data type
        if (dataType == HDFql.TinyInt || dataType == HDFql.VarTinyInt)
            System.Console.WriteLine("Data type is a char");
        else if (dataType == HDFql.UnsignedTinyInt || dataType == HDFql.UnsignedVarTinyInt)
            System.Console.WriteLine("Data type is an unsigned char");
        else if (dataType == HDFql.SmallInt || dataType == HDFql.VarSmallInt)
            System.Console.WriteLine("Data type is a short");
        else if (dataType == HDFql.UnsignedSmallInt || dataType == HDFql.UnsignedVarSmallInt)
            System.Console.WriteLine("Data type is an unsigned short");
        else if (dataType == HDFql.Int || dataType == HDFql.VarInt)
            System.Console.WriteLine("Data type is an int");
        else if (dataType == HDFql.UnsignedInt || dataType == HDFql.UnsignedVarInt)
            System.Console.WriteLine("Data type is an unsigned int");
        else if (dataType == HDFql.BigInt || dataType == HDFql.VarBigInt)
            System.Console.WriteLine("Data type is a long long");
        else if (dataType == HDFql.UnsignedBigInt || dataType == HDFql.UnsignedVarBigInt)
            System.Console.WriteLine("Data type is an unsigned long long");
        else if (dataType == HDFql.Float || dataType == HDFql.VarFloat)
            System.Console.WriteLine("Data type is a float");
        else if (dataType == HDFql.Double || dataType == HDFql.VarDouble)
            System.Console.WriteLine("Data type is a double");
        else if (dataType == HDFql.Char || dataType == HDFql.VarChar)
            System.Console.WriteLine("Data type is a char");
        else if (dataType == HDFql.Opaque)
            System.Console.WriteLine("Data type is an opaque");
        else if (dataType == HDFql.Enumeration)
            System.Console.WriteLine("Data type is an enumeration");
        else if (dataType == HDFql.Compound)
            System.Console.WriteLine("Data type is a compound");
        else
            System.Console.WriteLine("Unknown data type");

    }

}
```

In case you need to get the endianness or the size of the attribute `attrib`, execute `HDFql.Execute("SHOW ENDIANNESS attrib");` or `HDFql.Execute("SHOW SIZE attrib");`.